# Unable to load type error in Randoop

Tags: java, windows, command-prompt, randoop

When I try to run Randoop in the Windows terminal I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\dell13\workspace\project>java -classpath .;.\randoop-3.0.7\randoop-all-3.0.7.jar randoop.main.Main gentests --testclass=Factorial --timelimit=60
policy = sun.security.provider.PolicyFile@5fd0d5ae

Throwable thrown while handling command: java.lang.Error: Unable to load type "Factorial" due to exception: null
java.lang.Error: Unable to load type "Factorial" due to exception: null
    at randoop.main.ThrowClassNameError.handle(ThrowClassNameError.java:16)
    at randoop.reflection.OperationModel.addClassTypes(OperationModel.java:307)
    at randoop.reflection.OperationModel.createModel(OperationModel.java:132)
    at randoop.main.GenTests.handle(GenTests.java:193)
    at randoop.main.Main.nonStaticMain(Main.java:63)
    at randoop.main.Main.main(Main.java:27)

Randoop failed.
Last sequence under execution: null
```

The file I am trying to run Randoop on is Factorial.class which is located in the current working directory. The current working directory also contains the folder with all the randoop files/jars. I'm not sure why this is happening because I tried this on my Mac and it seemed to work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently the primary developer of Randoop, so I can tell you that this error is always because Java cannot find the class in the classpath. This is either because the name does not match the name of a class in the classpath, or the classpath is not correct.

I don't have a Windows machine, but, all Oracle documentation aside, it would appear that you need to put the classpath in double quotes.